# Override the Listbox Control to return a concatenated string value

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, listbox-control

I have to redefine the ListBox class to make sure that it returns a csv string of all the selected items and also should take in a csv string and populate the listbox when needed. Lets say I have this code. What are the functions that I have to override and how do I do it?

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace MY.WebControl
{
    public class ListBoxString : ListBox
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to do is add functionality, you can also add Extension Methods to add this capability.  Here are 2 quick examples that GetSelectItems to a CSV string and AddListItems from a string array.

```
    public static string GetSelectedItems(this ListBox lbox)
    {
        List<string> selectedValues = new List<string>();

        int[] selectedIndeces = lbox.GetSelectedIndices();

        foreach (int i in selectedIndeces)
            selectedValues.Add(lbox.Items[i].Value);

        return String.Join(",",selectedValues.ToArray());
    }

    public static void SetSelectedItems(this ListBox lbox, string[] values)
    {
        foreach (string value in values)
        {
            lbox.Items[lbox.Items.IndexOf(lbox.Items.FindByValue(value))].Selected = true;
        }
    }

    public static void AddListItems(this ListBox lbox, string[] values)
    {
        foreach (string value in values)
        {
            ListItem item = new ListItem(value);
            lbox.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Zach, When I said populating the ListBox, I meant selecting the data within the list box. For example I have A listbox with 
Chicago
New York
Dallas
San Francisco

And from my database say, the cities I visited are Dallas and Chicago. I get them from the database and when I load the form I want Chicago and Dallas to be selected in the Listbox.

Comment: I've just added a SetSelectedItems to the example above, if you prefer to use a CSV string, then change string[] to string and do a String.Split(',') on the input to convert to a string array.

Comment: Hi Zack, functions FindString and SetSelected belong to the    System.Windows.Forms.ListBox and not the  System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox. So I cant call them like you did in your code. Is there any other way to do that with the web controls?

Comment: Wow, how did I let that slip... things just meld together with .NET.  You just need to itterate over ListBox.Items, I'll update example above...

Comment: I have checked the protected void SetPostDataSelection (int selectedIndex) function. But, its Protected function so I cant call it from the object of ListBoxString. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you mean override? Or do you really mean "override and overload as appropriate?"

I'd overload the Add method to include an overload that takes a CSV string, parse it into an array of strings (or List) and pass it to AddRange.

I'd also override ToString() to return the values as a CSV list.

Comment: Thanks! I did override the ToString() with the definition from Zach and I got the functionality I needed.